# how to comment out multiple lines and give indentation in atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor, pyscripter

hi i am new to programming and i am using atom for python . but how can I comment out multiple lines and give indentation to multiple lines like pyscripter ?
is there any package for that ?

Comment: Highlight the block, press tab. Now press shift-tab. Now press `ctrl` + `/`. Or just look in the `Edit` dropdown...

Comment: not sure if this question is meant for this site, possibly another site

Answer (score 2):

To comment out multiple lines select the code you want to comment and Ctrl + /

To indent multiple lines select the code you would like to indent and press Tab. Press Shift + Tab to indent backwards.

For python I recommend the following packages:

- 'autocomplete-python' - Useful auto completion package, completes variables, methods, packages,and functions including their arguments.
- 'python-indent' - Gives indents after the use of ":" like IDLE does, useful so you don't have to Tab every time.
- 'atom-python-run' - Allows your python programs to be run straight from atom.

For the auto-complete and python-run packages you need to set them up, giving the path to your python directory, for them to run correctly.